# Disable Button if regular expression is not valid inside handsontable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex, handsontable

[image]

i need to validate three fields here **First Name , Last Name , & Email** only if these values are valid or if all fields are empty it should show `**Next**` button. All these Target Column values are coming from Api.

**First Name & Last Name** should accept only alphabets
**Email** should be asusual in Email format

```
dataObject.forEach(function (item) {
   var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;                        
   var emailReg = /^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/;

if (item.TargetColumn == "First Name" && item.DefaultValue.match(regex)) {
         $('#importNext').css({ 'display':'none'});
         alert("First Name is not valid")                           
         } else if (item.TargetColumn == "First Name" && item.DefaultValue == ""){
            console.log("Success");
            $('#importNext').css({ 'display': 'block' });
     }

   if (item.TargetColumn == "Last Name" && item.DefaultValue.match(regex)) {
         $('#importNext').css({ 'display':'none'});
         alert("Last Name is not valid")                           
         } else if (item.TargetColumn == "Last Name" && item.DefaultValue == ""){
            console.log("Success");
            $('#importNext').css({ 'display': 'block' });
     }

   if (item.TargetColumn == "Email" && !item.DefaultValue.match(emailReg)) {
         $('#importNext').css({ 'display':'none'});
         alert("Email is not valid")                           
         } else if (item.TargetColumn == "Email" && item.DefaultValue == ""){
            console.log("Success");
            $('#importNext').css({ 'display': 'block' });
     }
)};
```

I had tried above method but button is still visible

Comment: Hello, can you give an update regarding my answer? @chethu

Comment: @Prabusamvel  still same problem not able to hide the button if any one condition satisfies it will show Next button eventhough some invalid values are also there

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will helps you.

```js
var fields = ["First_Name", "Last_Name", "Location", "Email", "Experience", "ID"];
var fields_data = {};
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
 
 var html = "";
  
 fields.forEach(function(field){
  html += "<tr>";
  html += "<td style='text-align:right;'>"+field+":</td>";
  html += "<td><input type='text' class='tableFields' data-field='"+field+"'></td>";
  html += "</tr>";
 });
 
 html += "<tr>";
 html += "<td></td>"
 html += "<td style='text-align:center;'><button id='next-button'>Next</button></td>";
 html += "</tr>";
 
 $("#form-table").html(html);
 
 var err = 0;
 
 $("#form-table").on('change', '.tableFields', function(e){
  var field = $(this).data('field');
  var value = $(this).val();
  
  fields_data[field] = value;
  
  var text_space_regex = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/; 
  var email_regex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  
  switch(field){
    case 'First_Name':
    case 'Last_Name':
   if(value && !text_space_regex.test(value)){
    alert(field+" should accept only text!");
    err++;
   }else{
    err -= (err===0) ? 0 : 1;
   }
    break;  
    
    case 'Email':
   if(value && !email_regex.test(value)){
    alert(field+" is invalid!");
    err++;
   }else{
    err -= (err===0) ? 0 : 1;
   }
    break;
  }
  
  if(err > 0){
   $("#next-button").hide();
  }else{
   $("#next-button").show();
  }
  
 });
 
 $("#form-table").on('click', '#next-button', function(e){
  alert("success! (look at console for data)");
  console.log(fields_data);
 });
 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="margin-top:25px;">
   <table id="form-table"></table>
</div>
```